# ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES on multiple targets

Tags: cmake

I think I've stumbled on a CMAKE bug, but I can't find enough info online to confirm. Upon `make clean`, I want to delete two folders: `foo`, and `bar`. My problem is that I can only delete one.

This will delete `foo`

```
set_directory_properties( PROPERTIES
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo"
)
```

I expect this to delete `foo` and `bar`, but it only deletes `bar`

```
set_directory_properties( PROPERTIES
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo"
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar"
)
```

I also tried this, but got the same result as above:

```
set_directory_properties( PROPERTIES
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo"
)
set_directory_properties( PROPERTIES
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar"
)
```

Can someone please advise regarding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you split it into two `set_directories_properties()` calls?

Comment: Modern cmake update: since cmake 3.15 ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES is deprecated in favor of ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES, which can also be set on a target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_property` instead of `set_directory_properties`:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo"
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar")
```

Comment: @qweruiop The SET_DIRECTORIES_PROPERTIES version makes two instances of assignments, and the second instance does not append a new value to the existing one.

Comment: Close, you're just missing the APPEND option: 
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo"
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar")